# unable to validate SAML 2.0 assertion against schema

Tags: xsd, saml, xml-validation, spring-saml

I am working with [Spring SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) and I have problem consuming SAML assertion (sample assertion from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0)

```
<saml:Assertion
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    ID="b07b804c-7c29-ea16-7300-4f3d6f7928ac"
    Version="2.0"
   IssueInstant="2004-12-05T09:22:05">
   <saml:Issuer>https://idp.example.org/SAML2</saml:Issuer>
   <ds:Signature
     xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">...</ds:Signature>
   <saml:Subject>
     <saml:NameID
       Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">
       3f7b3dcf-1674-4ecd-92c8-1544f346baf8
     </saml:NameID>
     <saml:SubjectConfirmation
       Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
       <saml:SubjectConfirmationData
         InResponseTo="aaf23196-1773-2113-474a-fe114412ab72"
         Recipient="https://sp.example.com/SAML2/SSO/POST"
         NotOnOrAfter="2004-12-05T09:27:05"/>
     </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
   </saml:Subject>
   <saml:Conditions
     NotBefore="2004-12-05T09:17:05"
     NotOnOrAfter="2004-12-05T09:27:05">
     <saml:AudienceRestriction>
       <saml:Audience>https://sp.example.com/SAML2</saml:Audience>
     </saml:AudienceRestriction>
   </saml:Conditions>
   <saml:AuthnStatement
     AuthnInstant="2004-12-05T09:22:00"
     SessionIndex="b07b804c-7c29-ea16-7300-4f3d6f7928ac">
     <saml:AuthnContext>
       <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
         urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
      </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
     </saml:AuthnContext>
   </saml:AuthnStatement>
   <saml:AttributeStatement>
     <saml:Attribute
       xmlns:x500="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:attribute:X500"
       x500:Encoding="LDAP"
       NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
       Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1"
       FriendlyName="eduPersonAffiliation">
       <saml:AttributeValue
         xsi:type="xs:string">member</saml:AttributeValue>
       <saml:AttributeValue
         xsi:type="xs:string">staff</saml:AttributeValue>
     </saml:Attribute>
   </saml:AttributeStatement>
 </saml:Assertion>
```

I am getting errors from XML validation. The errors come even when I perform schema validation from IDE (Intelij IDEA tools->XML Actions->Validate)

It looks like xml schema in xenc-schema.xsd is not valid (should have inlcude rather than import). This code comes from xmltooling-1.4.4.jar library (latest version).

Is this bug in Spring SAML or xmltooling schema files, or am I doing something wrong?

My business case is  identity-provider-initiated SSO.
As described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_POST_Binding, point
5. Request the Assertion Consumer Service at the SP
I am consuming SAML assertion in POST request (body contains SAMLResponse=

Bellow  all errors

> - <...>\xmltooling-1.4.4.jar!\schema\xmldsig-core-schema.xsd Error:(2, 360) src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute,
>     'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#', of an  element
>     information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute,
>     'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion', of the imported document.
> - <...>\xmltooling-1.4.4.jar!\schema\xenc-schema.xsd Error:(2, 360) src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute,
>     'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#', of an  element
>     information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute,
>     'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion', of the imported document.
> - <...>\opensaml-2.6.4.jar!\schema\saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd Error:(34, 48) src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name
>     'xenc:EncryptedData' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
>     Error:(46, 56) src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to
>     a(n) 'element declaration' component.
> - <...>\wikipediaExample.xml Error:(11, 59) cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ds:Signature'. One of
>     '{"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":Subject,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":Conditions,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":Advice,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":Statement,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":AuthnStatement,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":AuthzDecisionStatement,
>     "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion":AttributeStatement}' is
>     expected. Error:(11, 77) cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'ds:Signature'
>     cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is
>     element-only. Error:(11, 77) cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of
>     element 'ds:Signature' is not complete. One of
>     '{"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":SignedInfo}' is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your XML, the Signature content is ommited with triple dots:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">...</ds:Signature>
```

The XML validation is correctly telling you about this problem.

Comment: right, the very last line of the error message points to root cause. I just wonder why error message is so long and misleading- why first lines mention some error in schema files?