# IntelliJ flags this SAML 2.0 metadata XML as failing XSD validation

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, saml-2.0, xsd-validation

IntelliJ flags this SAML 2.0 metadata XML document as failing XSD validation:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://localhost:8993/services/idp/login"
                     xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"
                         protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        ZGllIHRvdGVuIGhvc2Vu
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        aHVuZGVuYmVsbGVu
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                Location="https://localhost:8993/logout"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                Location="https://localhost:8993/logout"/>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                Location="https://localhost:8993/services/idp/login"/>
        <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                Location="https://localhost:8993/services/idp/login"/>
    </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

---

The XSD is here-- https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd

---

IntelliJ complains about a missing element `<EncryptionMethod>` when it sees the `<KeyInfo>` tag. But according to the spec, the EncryptionMethod element is *optional*. (https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf):

> EncryptionMethod [Zero or More] Optional element specifying an
>   algorithm and algorithm-specific settings supported by the entity.

The XSD sets min occurrences of `<EncryptionMethod>` to 0

> ```
>         <element ref="md:EncryptionMethod" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
> ```

---

Is IntelliJ correct that the XML document does not conform to the schema? Or is IntelliJ in error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to validate SAML 2.0 assertion against schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793059/unable-to-validate-saml-2-0-assertion-against-schema)